Returning an Ajax response which consists of HTML and JavaScript to the front end to be rendered
been trying for days to figure this out...im trying to call a shortcode via php, process it via Ajax and return the response to a frontend  but has been unable to do so.
It seems that the script just wont run despite the do_shortcode correctly outputs the correct response. the codes as below: (Enqueue of JS has been done in a separate php)
PHP
add_action('wp_ajax_get_amelia_shortcode', 'get_amelia_shortcode');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_amelia_shortcode', 'get_amelia_shortcode');

function get_amelia_shortcode() 
{
    if (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX) 
    {
          include_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/ameliabooking/ameliabooking.php';
           $output = do_shortcode('[ameliaeventscalendarbooking location=2]');
            error_log('Shortcode Output: ' . $output);
            echo $output;
    }
    wp_die();
}

JAVA
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#call-amelia-button').on('click', function () {
        const $ameliaContent = $('#amelia-content');

        $ameliaContent.text('Loading...').addClass('loading');

        // Perform AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: customAjax.ajaxurl, // Defined via wp_localize_script
            data: { action: 'get_amelia_shortcode' },
            success: function (response) {
    // Extract the script content and HTML content
    const $responseHTML = $('<div>').html(response); // Wrap response in a jQuery object

    // Insert the non-script parts of the response into the target
    const $ameliaContent = $('#amelia-content');
    $ameliaContent.html($responseHTML.find('*').not('script').clone()).removeClass('loading');

    // Execute scripts in the response
    $responseHTML.find('script').each(function () {
        const scriptContent = this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML;
        try {
            console.log("Response Content:", response);
            $.globalEval(scriptContent);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error executing script:", error);
        }
    });
},
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                // Handle errors gracefully
                $ameliaContent.text('An error occurred. Please try again later.').removeClass('loading');
            }
        });
    });
});

any help would be highly appreciated.
many thanks!
The aim is to trigger the Amelia booking plugin using do_shortcode() and update the frontend in realtime, the above is a simple execution to make sure the code works before implementing more complex logics and criteria to trigger the plugin with different params.

I gather $.globalEval(scriptContent); is supposed to evaluate the script. Does it run successfuly?

Hi thanks for your reply. I tried asking Ai the same thing but it says it will run but it seems that is not that case here... Any idea to make scripts run on front end when injected via Ajax?

Neither I nor AI can observe what your code ACTUALLY does. i.e. does console.log("Response Content:", response); run? what if you console.log(scriptContent) instead, does it show the correct script?

As Bravo says, have you tried actually debugging your code to find a specific issue, rather than asking bots to guess what is happening?
